# How to get sphinx to install with mysql support using homebrew

Tags: mysql, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I am attempting to get sphinx installed on my Mac OS X (10.8.3) laptop so that I can do some full text searching on a rails app using thinking sphinx.

The commands I have used for installing sphinx are:

`brew install sphinx --mysql`
and
`brew install sphinx --with-mysql=/usr/local/mysql`

Neither seem to work. Once sphinx is installed it simply says I need to install postgres or mysql in order to use it.

Does anyone know how I can force homebrew to install sphinx with mysql support?

Comment: Just to confirm: you do have MySQL installed on your machine, right? If so, how?

Comment: Yes I do have MySQL installed on my system. I used the binary installer from MySQL and its the 64bit version.

Comment: What's the output of `which mysql` in your shell?

Comment: The output from which mysql is /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql

Comment: I'm not sure why it's not working. I'd recommend trying to compile Sphinx yourself. It shouldn't be too tricky.